# Image is displaying in LinearLayout stretched?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I'm having trouble displaying my image within my `LinearLayout`. I'm trying to get a background color of white and have an `ImageView` displayed in my `LinearLayout` and the image and the background color works find, but the image is stretched.

What's a good way to proportion the image show that it displays normal? Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#FFFFFF">
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/day1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: How are you defining your ImageView? I would wager a guess you're using the wrong scaleType that is scaling disproportionately (e.g. fitXY)

Comment: Please show the XML of your layout, including the imageview.

Comment: I added the XML of my layout.

Comment: Try adding `android:scaleType="centerInside"` to the imageview xml

Comment: Initial thing I see wrong is the scrollview's width and height should be set to "wrap_content" as well as the LinearLayout's.  "fill_parent" in the context of a ScrollView is irrelevant as it goes on forever.

Comment: Thanks Aleks G. How did you learn android? Any tips?

Comment: @KD trial, error and google, honestly :)

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311502/2826147)