# How to get appropriate images in respective android Device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport, android-screen-support, mobile-devices

I'm designing the layout of Music Player. When I'm rendering it with the Nexus 5 virtual device, I'm not facing any problem at all

[image: image1]

When I render the image with Nexus 7 it is showing the same image size.

[image: image2]

Posting screenshot of my photo too.

Hope to get some solution from you guys.

Comment: share your xml layout and use dimensions for different screen size

Comment: im expecting you have different screen sizes of the images in every resource folder (eg. ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi)? if yes then the problem is your app not getting the right image for your device

Comment: I have not asked this question. ask this to questioner and see that first has asked question @HirenPatel

Comment: @Abhishek Dash, can you please post xml row file of gridview

Comment: check this answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311502/2826147

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this to support multiple devices :

**changes in screen density.**

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

**Make this layout files, so that it will be same for all devices**.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

**For Layout** ,

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

---

**For Images**

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

---

**For Icon**

```
res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

**For Launcher icon**

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)
```

> **NOTE:** Always try to use SP whenever you deal with `textSize`, like `textsize=12sp`

Use predefined `textAppearance`:

```
It will set text size automatically as per device density.

    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
Sample usage:

    <TextView
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:text="Sample Text - Small" />
    <TextView
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:text="Sample Text  - Medium" />
    <TextView
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:text="Sample Text  - Large" />
```

Please visit [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)