# Android 7" & 10" Tablets Layouts - sw600dp & sw720dp

Tags: android, android-layout, display

I have created an android application that is working fine in the mobile handsets. Now I want it to be compatible for 7" and 10" tablets as well. For this I have created drawable folders as well as layout folders (sw600dp for 7 and sw720dp for 10).

There are many 7 inches tablets in the market. With different pixel as well as screen density.
For instance - 7 inch tablets range from Width x Height (600 X 1024) to (1200 x 1920) with PPI ranging from 170 to 323.

Similarty 10 inch tablets range from Width x Height (768 X 1280) to (1600 x 2560) with PPI ranging from 132 to 300.

I have created my image resources in the sw600dp and sw720dp considering the base size of the 7 and 10 inch tablets which is 600 x 1024 and 768 x 1280. I have designed my layouts in a way that my application looks fine in both these pixel and PPI densities.

BUT WHAT ABOUT THE REST OF THE DEVICES? 
I need a way to make sure that my application looks great on all the 7 and 10 inches tablets available in the market. How do I achieve this?

Google has recommended that developer should focus on the density of the device rather its size but here problem is that If I try the DisplayMetrics to find the density of the current device and show my drawable and layouts accordingly - possibility is that I might display wrong drawable in wrong layouts since the PPI range of 7 inch (170 - 323) and 10 inch (132 - 300) overlap with each other.

How do I make sure to display right drawable and layouts for the current device? Do I need to create multiple drawable and layouts folders for the 7 inch and 10 inch tablets or will 2 drawable and 2 layouts (sw600dp and sw720dp) will suffice for this?
Kindly suggest as I am facing this problem for many days now. TIA.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311502/2826147

Comment: how did you achieve this? I am facing the same problem. I need to design the app for al the tablets and phones.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to check `DisplayMetrics` for all the devices. You need not worry about the "actual screen density"; instead look for the "generalized density".

From the docs,

> A set of six generalized densities:
>
> 1. ldpi (low) ~120dpi
> 2. mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
> 3. hdpi (high) ~240dpi
> 4. xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
> 5. xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
> 6. xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

You need to specify your layouts and drawables in their appropriate density specific folder to get them right on the different devices.

For example, you have some image to show, then create copies of that image with different dimensions (small size image for small display, large size image for large display). Once you get these images ready then put them into the density folders (for drawables it will be `drawable-hdpi/`, `drawable-mdpi/` etc). Thats it. Now when your app runs, system will detect the screen density and will take the image from appropriate folder.

For details on this, read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).