# imageview not maintaining position on all layouts in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-imageview, android-xml

I am having a problem with my layouts, my imageview and imagebutton seems to not stay in position when i view different screen sizes! like on the 5.4inch 480x584 screen the imageview does not maintain position and moves towards the top! what i tried was is creating a layout folder sw360dp for this screen size and its still giving me problems on other device screens when i view all screens! i have read through the developer documents and still cannot resolve this!,i have included my xml layout. thank you

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cropdream1">



    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/newbts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_win"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311502/2826147)

Comment: thanks for your reply but not what i am looking for, i already have these layouts from the link you provide but layout-large etc is deprecated and therefor should be sw600dp for tablets and sw360dp for smaller phones etc etc, the problem i am having is the imageview and imagebutton moving in the designer layout upon selecting different screen previews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing many different layout options i found where i was going wrong!
the background image i had placed in the first main relativeLayout should not be there and when testing on different screens the imageview was not adjusting with this!
the way i worked this out was to place a child RelativeLayout and set the background drawable here! then i place the imagview and imagebutton inside of this layout and now this scales correctly!
i hope this answer helps others.

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cropdream1">


    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/newbts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_win"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```