# Android layout: Why does radio button get cut off at bottom edge?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

Very new to this.  Design view looks fine on the screen emulator, but gets cut off when debugging on my physical phone.

[image]

I don't know what else to add.

Here is the activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SpinnerPrompt"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:id="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radMale"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/BtnCap"
    android:id="@+id/btnGenerate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerMinutes"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerMinutes"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnGenerate" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGenerate"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGenerate"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnGenerate">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Male"
        android:id="@+id/radMale"
        android:checked="true"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Female"
        android:id="@+id/radFemale"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

Here is the strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Name</string>
<string name="BtnCap">Generate!</string>
<string name="SpinnerPrompt">Choose Number:</string>
<string name="Male">Male</string>
<string name="Female">Female</string>
```

Comment: pls include screenshots

Comment: Updated the main post to include a screenshot.  Notice how the Female radio button is chopped off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is due to different screen sizes having different resolutions.**

please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311502/2826147

you can try using **weightSum**, it will solve your issue,

check this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMinutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="@string/SpinnerPrompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGenerate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerMinutes"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/BtnCap" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMinutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMinutes"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewMinutes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMinutes"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnGenerate" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnGenerate"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGenerate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGenerate"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radMale"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radFemale"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Female" />
    </RadioGroup >
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: So, width = match_parent forces it to expand the entire width?

Comment: height="0dp"  and layout_weight="1"  forced it to have zero height, instead of the height of the caption?   I'd think that would make it disappear, no?   What does weight do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without screenshots, but it seems like you are aligning your radio group to the end of your button. Because of this, there may not be enough area on your phone's screen to show all radio buttons which may be why it's getting cut.

But again, without screenshots it's difficult to say

**--Edit After seeing Screenshots--**

Have your XML file as follows. The problem was that the space in between the top of your button and the Parent top was too small to fit in two radio buttons

```
<TextView
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SpinnerPrompt"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:id="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Male"
        android:id="@+id/radMale"
        android:checked="true"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Female"
        android:id="@+id/radFemale"
        />
</RadioGroup>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerMinutes"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewMinutes" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/BtnCap"
    android:id="@+id/btnGenerate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnGenerate" />
```

Comment: Updated the main post to include a screenshot.  Notice how the Female radio button is chopped off.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  When I pasted your XML code over the original, I got the following rendering error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: That is happening because you are aligning a few objects to objects that haven't been initialized yet. I have edited my reply to remedy that

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

*We need to add the required **padding** to each radio button.*

**Before:**

*xml:*

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/color_white"
                style="@style/RadioDialog"
                android:button="@drawable/sel_ic_color_white"
                />
```

*output:*

[image]

**After:**

*xml:*

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/color_white"
                style="@style/RadioDialog"
                android:button="@drawable/sel_ic_color_white"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_m"
                />
```

*output:*

[image]