# Should we use different dimen files for different screen sizes

Tags: android, material-design

Currently, I'm developing Android app (phone only) and using only one size for different screen sizes, ie:

`dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="button_size">48dp</dimen>

<dimen name="text_size">16sp</dimen>
```

so in different screen sizes, we have only one size for components. And we go to this result: in small device, a `textview` can contain 10 chars but in larger device, a `textview` can contain 20 chars

And some developers use a `gradle` script to generate multiple `dimens` files in different folders based on the main `dimens` file like this:

`values-sw320dp`

`dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="button_size">48dp</dimen>

<dimen name="text_size">16sp</dimen>
```

`values-sw480dp`

`dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="button_size">52dp</dimen>

<dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
```

...

so the system will use the `dimens` based on device size. And we go to this result: in small device and larger device, a `textview` can contain the same char, ie: 12 chars.

My question is: which one is better for UI, UX? (using Google Material Design)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Comment: @AmitVaghela the solution is old, and I also have taken a look at this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but what I mean in my question is: which solution is better for UI, UX, and especially with Google Material Design

Comment: Allways use different dimens file for different devices and you can check my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311502/2826147)

Comment: @AmitVaghela yes, but it's for tablet and we use it with different layouts, but my question is for phone

Comment: it is not for tablet my friend it contains layout and dimens for small screen devices also

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to support multiple screen dimen [here](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below, this will set automatically based on device.

`?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` - For Medium font
`?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall` - For Small font

`?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge` - For Large font

Please check [Material guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-usage), To ensure usability for people with disabilities, give buttons a height of 36dp and give touchable targets a minimum height of 48dp.

Comment: it's not what I want to discuss, I want to use a custom dimen instead of system dimen

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use different dimens file for different devices. This will help you application view to be same across devices. If you keep same dimens for different devices then layout problem can also come. In some devices your layout will look perfectly fine but in another it will look very bad.

Android developer site also recommend to use different layout for supporting different devices.

Comment: checked and taken a look at some guides and they suggested to use `layouts` or `drawables`, found nothing for `dimens`

Comment: Create  layout ,layout Layoutsw600dp and sw720dp folder  create the views and dimens folder change the text for all folder    For example <dimen name="10dp">   <dimen name_tab="10dp"> <dimen name_tab10="10dp">